# is this folder structure possible in apache showing content for this urls?

Tags: apache-2.4

say i want to have this urls:

```
https://mysub.domain.com/   (1)
https://mysub.domain.com/matomo  (2)
https://mysub.domain.com/myapp (3)
```

in my folder structure i want to have php apps (1 and 2) and node api ( 3 , i will proxy this) like this:

```
/var/www/wordpress -> this should respond to 1
/var/www/matomo/ -> this should respond to 2
/var/www/myapp/ ->this should respond to 3
```

is that posible in any apache configuration that 1 show the content of folder "/var/www/wordpress" ? and 2 show the content of folder "/var/www/matomo" , if so how?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `DocumentRoot` to */var/www/wordpress* and either use symbolic links in the file system or `Alias` statements in Apache to redirect traffic for *matoma* or *myapp* to a different folder.

Check the Apache documentation for details: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside